# How to add a Hash object to an ActiveRecord class? Tried but migration fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want my ActiveRecord class `User` to contain options (a bunch of string key-values), so I wrote:

```
rails generate migration AddOptionsToUser options:Hash
```

It generated:

```
class AddOptionsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :options, :Hash
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :options
  end
end
```

I also added this line to my class `User`:

```
serialize :options, Hash
```

But the migration fails:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Hash' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `options` Hash
```

I am new to Rails, what is the usual way to store a bunch of string key-values in an ActiveRecord class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have ruby object as an attribute of the ActiveRecord model you should use `serialize` method inside your class for that attribute [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class)

Comment: I had it already: `serialize :options, Hash` in class User. But error

Comment: try to change type of the column in migration from `Hash` to `text` or `string`

Comment: If I use `rails generate migration AddOptionsToUser options:text` instead, it indeed works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Rails serializes things in to a (YAML) string. So in your database, the type should be string (or text).

```
class AddOptionsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
       add_column :assessments, :options, :string
    end

    def self.down
       remove_column :assessments, :options
    end
end
```

Comment: Indeed that's the solution! Accepting Bohdan who tipped about it first.