# Adding a Hash to an ActiveRecord Hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I read [How to add a Hash object to an ActiveRecord class? Tried but migration fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594409/how-to-add-a-hash-object-to-an-activerecord-class-tried-but-migration-fails) and followed the format there.

I tried:

```
class AddTestResponsesToSurveys < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :surveys, :responses, :hash
    end
end
```

When I run `rake db:migrate`, I get an error in my `schema.rb` file that says:

```
# Could not dump table "surveys" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'hash' for column 'responses'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the answer is within the post you link.

Answer (score 1):

generate migration with column type text

```
class AddTestResponsesToSurveys < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :surveys, :responses, :text
    end
end
```

And in your `Survey` model, add this

```
serialize :responses, Hash
```